# How to redirect https to http in Apache Tomcat 9

Tags: windows, tomcat

We have one application that uses Tomcat 9 and when anyone access with http://link/ it works but sometimes like a week or something Chrome or Edge changes http://link/ to https://link/ and web page not working. So we clear HSTS record in the browser. Is there anyway I can force https request to redirect to http. Here is server.xml below;

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"  relaxedQueryChars="[,]" redirectPort="8443"  compression="on" URIEncoding="UTF-8" compressionMinSize="2048" 
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" compressibleMimeType="application/vnd.sap.cvom+vbo,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,text/json,application/javascript,application/json"/>
```

I tried couple things online, but I can try again and I am not sure how to reproduce the issue because this happens randomly.